# WCF service is added but, service reference instance is unavaiable into MVC 4 client applicaiton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-binding

I have crated WCF service.

Service client as - MVC 4 application. Added - Service reference into MVC 4 applicaiton.

Problem: In client application, unable to find - servicerefernececlient object to access service methods.

When i add same service reference into asp.net web applicaiton then it works and available to call service method. But, it is unavailable while access through MVC application.

DETAIL: In my solution there are three projects as follow: 1) WCF Applications ervice 2) ASP.NET Web Application 3) MVC 4 application.

WCF Applicaton service refernec added into both the projects using "Add service reference" . NOw, service reference instance is available into ASP.NET WEB applicaiton but, its not available into MVC 4 applicaiton.

Please suggest solution.

Please guide.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

can you describe it in more detail? The service reference is shown in your solution explorer like in a normal asp.net classic application? How do you generate the service client? Using Visual Studio via right-click > Add > Service Reference?

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to StackOverflow :) Your answer is something you would typically ask in a comment below the question since it is not actually an answer but a request to clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks Ronald! I'm not allowed to comment a question, because I don't have enough reputation :( But I will follow your suggestion in future!